How to add a quit option in a program with int input? [Java]
Learning Java in school currently and writing the classic "guess a number" game. I have to add an additional option to quit out mid-program, but am a little stuck on how to properly add that ability? I'm mostly confused on how I'd be able to do this given the scanner is asking for an int, where I want the string "quit" to allow the user to exit.
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class NumberGuesser {

        public static void playGuess() {
            // method created to run all the game logic when the main method calls it
            Random rand = new Random();
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int answer = rand.nextInt(50 - -50 + 1) + -50;
            int totalGuesses = 1;
            //  storing random + input + guess count
            while (true) {
                // while loop to run while method is called + random excluded to not create new one each guess
                System.out.println("Please enter a number between -50 and 50.");
                int guess = sc.nextInt();

                if  (guess > 50 || guess < -50) {
                    // incorrect entry handling first (does not add to count if incorrect)
                    System.out.println("Incorrect entry.");

                } else if (guess == answer) {
                    // correct answer check + break
                    System.out.println("Correct! It took you " + totalGuesses + " guesses.");
                    break;

                } else if(guess < answer) {
                    // if guess is less than + adds to count
                    System.out.println("The number is higher.");
                    totalGuesses++;

                } else if(guess > answer) {
                    // if guess is more than + adds to count
                    System.out.println("The number is lower.");
                    totalGuesses++;

                }
            }
        }

        public static void main (String[]args) {
        // main method to call the game + prompt to play again
        boolean playAgain = true;

        do {
            // call game when user input is y + ends program if not
            playGuess();
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Y/N.");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String answer = sc.nextLine();
            playAgain = answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y");
         }  while (playAgain);
    }
}


Enter an out-of-bounds number to exit like 100?

What do you mean by "quit out mid-program" ? It would clarify the question if you included an example.  Would you like to play again? Y/N. Y Please enter a number between -50 and 50. quit

Read input as a String using sc.nextLine(). Check if it equals "quit", otherwise parse it as an Integer and proceed as you do right now.

Just enter the EOF character: ctrl/d on Windows, ctrl/z on Unix and Linux.

Instead of using sc.nextInt(), you can get the user input as a string using sc.nextLine(), check for the word quit, and then either exit the program or convert the input to a number.
int guess;
String input = sc.nextLine();
    if(input.equals("quit"))
        System.exit(0);
    else 
        guess = Integer.parseInt(input);


Hey that helps a lot, thanks! Just a rookie follow-up, why aren't you bracketing the if/else? Is that something I'm not required to do on if statements? I was under the impression I was.

You only need to do it if there is more than one Statement after the if / else /for etc. ... You can find the documentation here under Blocks.

re: using / omitting braces, sure they're optional but skipping them leads to subtle bugs. From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html - "Deciding when to omit the braces is a matter of personal taste. Omitting them can make the code more brittle. If a second statement is later added to the "then" clause, a common mistake would be forgetting to add the newly required braces. The compiler cannot catch this sort of error; you'll just get the wrong results."
